# Pod cannot mount Persistent Volume created by ozone CSI provisioner

Tags: kubernetes, ozone

I am using kubernetes to deploy [ozone](https://ozone.apache.org/downloads/) (a sub for hdfs), and basically followed instructions from [here](https://ozone.apache.org/docs/1.1.0/start/kubernetes.html) and [here](https://ozone.apache.org/docs/1.1.0/interface/csi.html) (just a few steps).

First I created few pvs with hostpath to my local dir, then I slightly edited the yamls from `ozone/kubernetes/example/ozone` by changing nfs claim to host path claim:

```
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: data
    spec:
      storageClassName: manual
      accessModes: ["ReadWriteOnce"]
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 5Gi
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          type: local
```

and I commented out the nodeAffinity settings in datanode-stateful.yaml since my kubernetes only had master node.

The deployment was succesful.

Then I applied the csi and pv-test as the instructions in csi protocol said, the pv (bucket in s3v) was automatically established, and pvc did bound the pv, but the test pod stopped at `containerCreating`.

Attaching the pv-test pod desc:

```
Name:           ozone-csi-test-webserver-778c8c87b7-rngfk
Namespace:      default
Priority:       0
Node:           k8s-master/192.168.100.202
Start Time:     Fri, 18 Jun 2021 14:23:54 +0800
Labels:         app=ozone-csi-test-webserver
                pod-template-hash=778c8c87b7
Annotations:    <none>
Status:         Pending
IP:
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/ozone-csi-test-webserver-778c8c87b7
Containers:
  web:
    Container ID:
    Image:         python:3.7.3-alpine3.8
    Image ID:
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Args:
      python
      -m
      http.server
      --directory
      /www
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       ContainerCreating
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-gqknv (ro)
      /www from webroot (rw)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  webroot:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  ozone-csi-test-webserver
    ReadOnly:   false
  default-token-gqknv:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-gqknv
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason       Age                   From                 Message
  ----     ------       ----                  ----                 -------
  Warning  FailedMount  7m7s (x58 over 122m)  kubelet, k8s-master  MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "pvc-1913bd70-09fd-4eba-a459-73fe3bd397b8" : rpc error: code = Unknown desc =
  Warning  FailedMount  31s (x54 over 120m)   kubelet, k8s-master  Unable to mount volumes for pod "ozone-csi-test-webserver-778c8c87b7-rngfk_default(b1a59143-00b9-47f6-94fe-1845c29aee93)": timeout expired waiting for volumes to attach or mount for pod "default"/"ozone-csi-test-webserver-778c8c87b7-rngfk". list of unmounted volumes=[webroot]. list of unattached volumes=[webroot default-token-gqknv]
```

Attach events for the whole process:

```
7m51s   Normal    SuccessfulCreate        statefulset/s3g                                  create Claim data-s3g-0 Pod s3g-0 in StatefulSet s3g success
7m51s   Warning   FailedScheduling        pod/s3g-0                                        pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims (repeated 2 times)
7m51s   Normal    SuccessfulCreate        statefulset/scm                                  create Pod scm-0 in StatefulSet scm successful
7m51s   Normal    SuccessfulCreate        statefulset/om                                   create Pod om-0 in StatefulSet om successful
7m51s   Warning   FailedScheduling        pod/om-0                                         pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims (repeated 2 times)
7m51s   Warning   FailedScheduling        pod/datanode-0                                   pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims (repeated 2 times)
7m51s   Normal    SuccessfulCreate        statefulset/datanode                             create Pod datanode-0 in StatefulSet datanode successful
7m51s   Normal    SuccessfulCreate        statefulset/datanode                             create Claim data-datanode-0 Pod datanode-0 in StatefulSet datanode success
7m51s   Normal    SuccessfulCreate        statefulset/scm                                  create Claim data-scm-0 Pod scm-0 in StatefulSet scm success
7m51s   Normal    SuccessfulCreate        statefulset/s3g                                  create Pod s3g-0 in StatefulSet s3g successful
7m51s   Normal    SuccessfulCreate        statefulset/om                                   create Claim data-om-0 Pod om-0 in StatefulSet om success
7m51s   Warning   FailedScheduling        pod/scm-0                                        pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims (repeated 2 times)
7m50s   Normal    Scheduled               pod/s3g-0                                        Successfully assigned default/s3g-0 to hadoop104
7m50s   Normal    Scheduled               pod/datanode-0                                   Successfully assigned default/datanode-0 to hadoop103
7m50s   Normal    Scheduled               pod/scm-0                                        Successfully assigned default/scm-0 to hadoop104
7m50s   Normal    Scheduled               pod/om-0                                         Successfully assigned default/om-0 to hadoop103
7m49s   Normal    Created                 pod/datanode-0                                   Created container datanode
7m49s   Normal    Started                 pod/datanode-0                                   Started container datanode
7m49s   Normal    Pulled                  pod/datanode-0                                   Container image "apache/ozone:1.1.0" already present on machine
7m48s   Normal    SuccessfulCreate        statefulset/datanode                             create Claim data-datanode-1 Pod datanode-1 in StatefulSet datanode success
7m48s   Warning   FailedScheduling        pod/datanode-1                                   pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims (repeated 2 times)
7m48s   Normal    Pulled                  pod/scm-0                                        Container image "apache/ozone:1.1.0" already present on machine
7m48s   Normal    Created                 pod/scm-0                                        Created container init
7m48s   Normal    Started                 pod/scm-0                                        Started container init
7m48s   Normal    Pulled                  pod/s3g-0                                        Container image "apache/ozone:1.1.0" already present on machine
7m48s   Normal    Created                 pod/s3g-0                                        Created container s3g
7m48s   Normal    Started                 pod/s3g-0                                        Started container s3g
7m48s   Normal    SuccessfulCreate        statefulset/datanode                             create Pod datanode-1 in StatefulSet datanode successful
7m46s   Normal    Scheduled               pod/datanode-1                                   Successfully assigned default/datanode-1 to hadoop104
7m45s   Normal    Created                 pod/datanode-1                                   Created container datanode
7m45s   Normal    Pulled                  pod/datanode-1                                   Container image "apache/ozone:1.1.0" already present on machine
7m44s   Normal    Created                 pod/scm-0                                        Created container scm
7m44s   Normal    Started                 pod/scm-0                                        Started container scm
7m44s   Normal    Started                 pod/datanode-1                                   Started container datanode
7m44s   Normal    Pulled                  pod/scm-0                                        Container image "apache/ozone:1.1.0" already present on machine
7m43s   Warning   FailedScheduling        pod/datanode-2                                   pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims (repeated 2 times)
7m43s   Normal    SuccessfulCreate        statefulset/datanode                             create Pod datanode-2 in StatefulSet datanode successful
7m43s   Normal    SuccessfulCreate        statefulset/datanode                             create Claim data-datanode-2 Pod datanode-2 in StatefulSet datanode success
7m42s   Normal    Scheduled               pod/datanode-2                                   Successfully assigned default/datanode-2 to hadoop103
7m38s   Normal    Pulled                  pod/datanode-2                                   Container image "apache/ozone:1.1.0" already present on machine
7m38s   Normal    Created                 pod/datanode-2                                   Created container datanode
7m38s   Normal    Started                 pod/datanode-2                                   Started container datanode
7m23s   Normal    ScalingReplicaSet       deployment/csi-provisioner                       Scaled up replica set csi-provisioner-5649bc9474 to 1
7m23s   Warning   FailedCreate            daemonset/csi-node                               Error creating: pods "csi-node-" is forbidden: error looking up service account default/csi-ozone: serviceaccount "csi-ozone" not found
7m22s   Normal    Scheduled               pod/csi-node-nbfnw                               Successfully assigned default/csi-node-nbfnw to hadoop104
7m22s   Normal    Scheduled               pod/csi-provisioner-5649bc9474-n5jf2             Successfully assigned default/csi-provisioner-5649bc9474-n5jf2 to hadoop103
7m22s   Normal    SuccessfulCreate        replicaset/csi-provisioner-5649bc9474            Created pod: csi-provisioner-5649bc9474-n5jf2
7m22s   Normal    Scheduled               pod/csi-node-c97fz                               Successfully assigned default/csi-node-c97fz to hadoop103
7m22s   Normal    SuccessfulCreate        daemonset/csi-node                               Created pod: csi-node-c97fz
7m22s   Normal    SuccessfulCreate        daemonset/csi-node                               Created pod: csi-node-nbfnw
7m14s   Normal    Pulling                 pod/csi-node-c97fz                               Pulling image "quay.io/k8scsi/csi-node-driver-registrar:v1.0.2"
7m14s   Normal    Pulling                 pod/csi-provisioner-5649bc9474-n5jf2             Pulling image "quay.io/k8scsi/csi-provisioner:v1.0.1"
7m13s   Normal    Pulling                 pod/csi-node-nbfnw                               Pulling image "quay.io/k8scsi/csi-node-driver-registrar:v1.0.2"
6m56s   Warning   Unhealthy               pod/om-0                                         Liveness probe failed: dial tcp 10.244.1.7:9862: connect: connection refused
6m56s   Normal    Killing                 pod/om-0                                         Container om failed liveness probe, will be restarted
6m55s   Normal    Created                 pod/om-0                                         Created container om
6m55s   Normal    Started                 pod/om-0                                         Started container om
6m55s   Normal    Pulled                  pod/om-0                                         Container image "apache/ozone:1.1.0" already present on machine
6m48s   Normal    Pulled                  pod/csi-provisioner-5649bc9474-n5jf2             Successfully pulled image "quay.io/k8scsi/csi-provisioner:v1.0.1"
6m48s   Normal    Started                 pod/csi-provisioner-5649bc9474-n5jf2             Started container ozone-csi
6m48s   Normal    Created                 pod/csi-provisioner-5649bc9474-n5jf2             Created container ozone-csi
6m48s   Normal    Pulled                  pod/csi-provisioner-5649bc9474-n5jf2             Container image "apache/ozone:1.1.0" already present on machine
6m48s   Normal    Started                 pod/csi-provisioner-5649bc9474-n5jf2             Started container csi-provisioner
6m48s   Normal    Created                 pod/csi-provisioner-5649bc9474-n5jf2             Created container csi-provisioner
6m45s   Normal    Pulled                  pod/csi-node-nbfnw                               Successfully pulled image "quay.io/k8scsi/csi-node-driver-registrar:v1.0.2"
6m44s   Normal    Started                 pod/csi-node-nbfnw                               Started container driver-registrar
6m44s   Normal    Started                 pod/csi-node-nbfnw                               Started container csi-node
6m44s   Normal    Created                 pod/csi-node-nbfnw                               Created container csi-node
6m44s   Normal    Created                 pod/csi-node-nbfnw                               Created container driver-registrar
6m44s   Normal    Pulled                  pod/csi-node-nbfnw                               Container image "apache/ozone:1.1.0" already present on machine
6m25s   Normal    Pulled                  pod/csi-node-c97fz                               Successfully pulled image "quay.io/k8scsi/csi-node-driver-registrar:v1.0.2"
6m25s   Normal    Pulled                  pod/csi-node-c97fz                               Container image "apache/ozone:1.1.0" already present on machine
6m25s   Normal    Started                 pod/csi-node-c97fz                               Started container csi-node
6m25s   Normal    Created                 pod/csi-node-c97fz                               Created container csi-node
6m17s   Normal    Created                 pod/csi-node-c97fz                               Created container driver-registrar
6m17s   Normal    Pulled                  pod/csi-node-c97fz                               Container image "quay.io/k8scsi/csi-node-driver-registrar:v1.0.2" already present on machine
6m17s   Normal    Started                 pod/csi-node-c97fz                               Started container driver-registrar
6m3s    Normal    Provisioning            persistentvolumeclaim/ozone-csi-test-webserver   External provisioner is provisioning volume for claim "default/ozone-csi-test-webserver"
6m3s    Normal    ScalingReplicaSet       deployment/ozone-csi-test-webserver              Scaled up replica set ozone-csi-test-webserver-7cbdc5d65c to 1
6m3s    Normal    SuccessfulCreate        replicaset/ozone-csi-test-webserver-7cbdc5d65c   Created pod: ozone-csi-test-webserver-7cbdc5d65c-dpzhc
6m3s    Normal    ExternalProvisioning    persistentvolumeclaim/ozone-csi-test-webserver   waiting for a volume to be created, either by external provisioner "org.apache.hadoop.ozone" or manually created by system administrator
6m2s    Warning   FailedScheduling        pod/ozone-csi-test-webserver-7cbdc5d65c-dpzhc    pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims (repeated 2 times)
6m1s    Normal    ProvisioningSucceeded   persistentvolumeclaim/ozone-csi-test-webserver   Successfully provisioned volume pvc-cd01c58d-793f-41ce-9e12-057ade02e07c
5m59s   Normal    Scheduled               pod/ozone-csi-test-webserver-7cbdc5d65c-dpzhc    Successfully assigned default/ozone-csi-test-webserver-7cbdc5d65c-dpzhc to hadoop104
97s     Warning   FailedMount             pod/ozone-csi-test-webserver-7cbdc5d65c-dpzhc    Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[webroot], unattached volumes=[webroot default-token-l9lng]: timed out waiting for the condition
94s     Warning   FailedMount             pod/ozone-csi-test-webserver-7cbdc5d65c-dpzhc    MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "pvc-cd01c58d-793f-41ce-9e12-057ade02e07c" : kubernetes.io/csi: mounter.SetupAt failed: rpc error: code = Unknown desc =
```

Comment: Please add to your post the output of `kubectl -n <namespace> get events --sort-by='{.lastTimestamp}' where `<namespace>` is the namespace where those pods are scheduled.

Comment: events are attached, thank you

Comment: You deployed a csi-ozone storage provisioner, and associate it with `ozone` storage class, and then decided not to use it at all in pv-test. In other words, you opt for `storageClassName: manual` instead of `ozone`. If you tweaked also a default names used in `ozone/kubernetes/example/ozone` please share your modes too, so that we can better understand your setup.